# Linux equivalent of windows pipeline

Tags: windows, linux, bash, command-line, command-prompt

First question is, what would pipeline (|) mean in windows cmd?

Second question is, what would be the linux equivalent of windows pipeline?

Comment: This question could have been better researched.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows `cmd`, a `|` causes the output of one command to become the input of a second command:

```
command1 | command2
```

Linux shells use the same syntax, with the same meaning.

Comment: And historically, Unix pipes pre-existed Windows (Microsoft took years to add that important feature inside their OSes). So Windows copied Unix (not the other way round).